# Merge Unallocated Space BEFORE partition (W2K8R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, partition, hard-drive, diskmanagement

My Windows Server 2008 R2 Disk Management looks as follows:

```
    100 GB    100GB 
[Unallocated][(C:\)]
      X         Y
```

I accidentally installed Windows into the second partition (**Y**) instead of the first (**X**). Is there a way to safely merge X + Y into a single partition without having to wipe everything and re-install?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the Disk Management MMC or with diskpart but you can probably do it with GParted.

Comment: Can you tell me how please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GParted](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gparted&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://gparted.sourceforge.net/&ei=-33PUKDsOuu10AGj3oDYCA&usg=AFQjCNE-yW-wQWqO1Bav4GDAUXMWTtaq8A&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.dmQ) to do this. You will need to boot the server from the gparted ISO.

Here's a [super easy tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html). GParted is very easy to use.